# How can I send an email using angular meteor then add a template design in the email? I'm using this:

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

startup.js

smtp = {
    username: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    password: 'alpha123e',
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465
  }

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

Meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({ sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

this.unblock();

Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  text: text
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a templated design in your email then you'll want to set the `html` property of the email, not just the `text`.

```
Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
  text: "Hello World"
});
```

You will find the [meteorhacks:ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) package very useful for rendering templates server-side.